# How Use loop's in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d

I've for loop which work well on Windows

```
double speed = 35;

    for(int i=0; i<60 ;i++){

        speed += 0.3;
        Sleep (1000); // sleep 1000 mili seonds

     }
```

But it responds an error on cocos2d-x.what should i do in cocos2d-x.
In my code i want to increase my speed to N unit every X second.

```
auto Action = MoveBy::create(3  *   visibleSize.width,Point(-visibleSize.width * speed, 0));
```

My way is right or should I do something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another method, using a little bit more complex lambda:

1. First some setup, like initial movement speed and time between speed increases:

   ```
   float speed = 0;
   float delay = 1;
   ```
2. Here's the tricky part! I'm using `CallFuncN` since I want to run a new action (with new speed) every `delay` seconds. So I need to know to which Node I should attack new MoveBy action. Note that, this lambda is mutable, which means it might be changing it's capture values, and those changes should be retained between different calls.

   ```
   auto moveFunc = CallFuncN::create([speed, delay](Node *target) mutable
   {
       speed += 10;
       target->runAction(MoveBy::Create(Vec2(speed,0), delay));
   }
   ```
3. As Droideka suggested, we should create a sequence. CallFuncN takes no time to complete, but we don't want object to be moved second or third time, while the first one is still in progress, so we just have to wait. Note that `nullptr` should be there in it's last argument, it means there are no more actions in the sequence.

   ```
   auto sequence = Sequence::Create(moveFunc, DelayTime::create(delay), nullptr);
   ```
4. Also we don't want this to happen only once, or else we could simply run a `MoveBy` action. So we wrap the whole sequence inside a `Repeat` Action, which means this should be run more than once (in this code 5 times).

   ```
   auto repeat = Repeat::create(sequence,5);
   ```
5. Finally we need to attack this whole thing to an object, for example our player. Note that you just need to call these once and everything will happen according to plan afterwards.

   ```
   player->runAction(repeat);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Create an action with a callback to your function:

   ```
   CallFunc *runCallback = CallFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_0(Youclass::theFunc, this));
   ```
2. Create a delay With Delaytime class:

   ```
   // for 1 second
   auto delay = DelayTime::create(1);
   ```
3. Create a sequence with the delay and your runCallback function in the part of the code that you need to sleep it.

   ```
   this->runAction(Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(yourDelayTime), runCallback, nullptr));
   ```

Comment: I guess you meant `Sequence::create(delay,runCallback, nullptr)`.
Also personally I prefer using lambda instead of member function: `Callfunc::create([this](){speed += 0.3;})`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this code work but what you need can be accomplished easily with a `Scheduler` as this:

```
Schedule( [&](float dt) {
                        speed+= 0.3;
                        if(speed==N) Unschedule("TimerID");
                        } , 1, "TimerID");
```